# Expand a string describing a set of numbers noted as a list of numbers and/or ranges

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a string which describes a set of numbers. The numbers are listed in order, but a range of consecutive numbers can be abbreviated with a "range" using a hyphen/dash.

Example: "`001,008-011,020`"

I want to interpret this string this as an ordered list: `[ 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20 ]`

There could be a arbitrary number of ranges and elements.

Comment: Do you have a question? Have you tried this yourself? What did you come up with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the following..

```
>>> def findval(str):
...     val = []
...     for x in str.split(','):
...         if '-' in x:
...            lnum, rnum = x.split('-')
...            lnum, rnum = int(lnum), int(rnum)
...            val.extend(range(lnum, rnum + 1))
...         else:
...            lnum = int(x)
...            val.append(lnum)
...     return val

>>> findval('001,008-011,020')
[1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/80680)

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the string will always be in that format...

```
x =  "001,008-011,020"

x = x.split(',') # Split at the commas

y = []

# Iterate over the list
for i in x:
    try:
        # Will append the integer to your output list
        y.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        # If you get a ValueError (from trying to int('008-011') for example)
        # then split the string at the hyphen and individually append
        # the integers in between.
        j = i.split('-')
        for k in range(int(j[0]), int(j[1])+1):
            y.append(k)
```

I think that should work, though you may want to check that no other ValueErrors will be inadvertantly caught in the try/except loop.

Answer (score 3):

Implement something like so, capturing the range and iterating based on the integer value:

```
str = "001,008-011,020"
spl = str.split(",")
output = []
for s in spl:
    if '-' in s:
        rng = s.split(r"-")
        for r in range(int(rng[0]), int(rng[1])+1):
            output.append(r)
    else:
        output.append(int(s))

print output
```

prints:

```
[1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]
```

Comment: You're missing the last number in a range, I think you want int(rng[1])+1 otherwise you're just getting 8,9,10 for the range 008-011

Comment: There was a catch below it, but I moved it up into the range.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
def expand(s):
    parts = (map(int, x.split('-')) for x in s.split(','))
    return (n for p in parts for n in range(p[0], p[-1]+1))
```

after which

```
>>> expand("001")
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x901b784>
>>> list(expand("001"))
[1]
>>> list(expand("001,008-011,020"))
[1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]
```

Comment: Nice and short answer (but not as clear with the inline for-loops).